# OutOfMemoryException error in Loop

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, list, image-processing

I am trying to create a Windows app which uploads files to FTP. Essentially, it looks for .jpeg files in a given folder, it reads through the barcodes found in the .jpg files before uploading it into the FTP server, and entering the URL into the database for our records.

As there will be multiple files at any given time in the folder, I am essentially trying to read them in a loop, and process them accordingly. However, I get an OutOfMemoryException whenever the loop starts again. I am trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I have appended my code below:

```
private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    podPath = Directory.GetFiles(DestPath, "*.jpg");
    List<string> scans = new List<string>(podPath.Length);
    List<string> badscans = new List<string>();
    byte[] imageBytes;
    string filename, result;
    POD conpod = new POD();
    OTPOD otpod = new OTPOD();
    ConsignmentObj scanJob;
    //Pickup OTScan;
    //Consolidate ccv;

    for (int i = 0; i < podPath.Count(); i++ )
    {
        filename = podPath[i].ToString();

        using (Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(filename))
        {
            var results = barcodeReader.Decode(bm);
            result = results.ToString();
            bm.Dispose();
        }

        if (result != null)
        {
            //if barcode can be read, we throw the value into the database to pull out relevant information
            if (result.Contains(ConNotePrefix))
            {
                #region Consignments
                scanJob = getCon(result.ToString());
                final = ImageFolder + "\\" + result.ToString() + ".jpg";

                using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename))
                {
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    try
                    {
                        img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
                        img.Dispose();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        ms.Flush();
                        ms.Close();
                        ms.Dispose();
                    } 
                }

                lock (filename)
                {
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
                    {
                        File.Delete(filename);
                    }
                }

                using (var stream = File.Create(final)) { }
                File.WriteAllBytes(final, imageBytes);
                File.Delete(filename);

                conpod.ConsignmentID = scanJob.ConsignmentID;
                conpod.UserID = 1;
                conpod.Location = ftpUrl + "//" + result.ToString() + ".jpg";
                conpod.rowguid = Guid.NewGuid();

                UploadFilesToFtp(ftpUrl, ftpUser, ftpPass, final, result.ToString() + ".jpg");
                insertPOD(conpod);
                scans.Add(result.ToString());
                #endregion
                }
            }
            else
            {
                badscans.Add(filename);
            }
        }
    this.lbScans.ItemsSource = scans;
    this.lbBadScans.ItemsSource = badscans;
}
```

The FTP method, UploadFilesToFtp(x, x, x, x, x, x) is not a problem here. All feedback will be much appreciated.

Comment: How many items result from a call to `podPath.Count()`? `OutOfMemory` is exactly what it sounds like.. your process has reached the upper bounds of its memory limit.

Comment: I could probably try podPath.Length() and see what I get. Thanks.

Comment: the field `barcodeReader` what type of class is that? Maybe the Decode method of that class is the problem

Comment: That won't help. What I mean is.. you're obviously creating a gigantic list of items there.. which is governed by how many items are in the `podPath` collection to begin with. How many are there?

Comment: Is this on purpose btw: `using (var stream = File.Create(final)) { }` ?

Comment: For testing purposes, I have about 15 jpegs.

Comment: How big are they? You need to audit how much memory you're using at each iteration of your loop. Check each one.. step through the method line by line. Unfortunately we can't help you do that.

Comment: About 5-6mb on average.

Comment: @Jehof, the Decode method reads the barcode on each jpg file.

Comment: Also.. why are you locking on a string object? Is this multi-threaded? What does `insertPod` do? I really think you're on your own with this one. You have to put breakpoints everywhere and step through it. Also, use a profiler.

Comment: As an aside, calling `bm.Dispose()` is redundant.  When the using block ends, `Dispose` will be called automatically.  The same is true where you call `img.Dispose()`

Answer (score 4):

An `OutOfMemoryException` can also be thrown by the method [FromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `Image` class when

> The file does not have a valid image format.
>
> or
>
> GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.

So i think there is a problem with one of your image files you are reading. One solution is to catch the `OutOfMemoryException` and adding the file to the `badscans`.

```
try{
  using (Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(filename)) {
    var results = barcodeReader.Decode(bm);
    result = results.ToString();
    bm.Dispose();
  }
}
catch(OutOfMemoryException) {
  badscans.add(filename);
}
```

Comment: Seems an odd exception type for these format problems. Does this `OutOfMemoryException` wrap an inner exception (or have a message) that explains the real problem?

Comment: @groverboy i think that it contains some GDI+ error codes or other information, but i cannot verify it, cause i have no bad image file present.